# Firebase Dynamic Link on iOS TestFlight breaks query, react-native, Expo

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, testflight, firebase-dynamic-links

My dynamic link from Firebase to TestFlight app recently stopped working.

Link:

```
{firebase_domain.page.link}/?link={my_site}/?type=password-reset&token={jwt}&ibi={apple_bunle_id}&isi={apple_ID}
```

Open in Firefox focus. All other options - from embed to separate site to click, or gmail, or safari lead to AppStore by apple_ID of app - and it’s empty, because it’s TestFlight.

The problem is that I receive a malformed link from firebase as:

```
{apple_bunle_id}://google/link?deep_link_id={my_site}%2F%3Ftype%3Dpassword-reset&lt=DDL_LONG&lid=temp_link_id&utm_medium=dynamic_link&utm_source=firebase
```

So instead of parsed token I receive nothing.

It was working recently, and works on Android.
Link works on Expo GO if you replace {firebase_domain.page.link} with local expo url. (Universal link probably)

`{firebase_domain.page.link}/apple-app-site-association` set up properly
{my_site} and {firebase_domain.page.link} added to as associatedDomains without formatting

My iOS config from app.json

```
"ios": {
  "bundleIdentifier": {apple_bunle_id},
  "supportsTablet": false,
  "googleServicesFile": "./GoogleService-Info.plist",
  "buildNumber": "47.9",
  "associatedDomains": ["applinks:{my_site}", "applinks:{firebase_domain.page.link}",        "applinks:{my_site2}"]
}
```

My Linking prefixes config:

```
  prefixes: ['{universal_link_name}', Linking.makeUrl({firebase_domain.page.link}), Linking.makeUrl({apple_bunle_id})],
```

Comment: Interesting. I found a similar edge case and i have a solution for the domain i'm working on. Interested to know how you solved it? and im going to check why "://google/link?deep_link_id=" sort of url is received instead.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm experiencing the same problem